# Difference between pi camera & usb HD cam

Tags: raspbian, opencv

I am working on image processing project where working on frames taken by camera using raspberry pi.
So i want to know which is better ? to use pi camera or usb cam ,
Hint : required good camera as the mouse is moving corresponding to object detected by camera.

Answer (score 1):

Most obvious difference is , you can have USB cameras based on pixel quality and zooming and resolution; whereas Pi cam is limited:)

For image processing preferably using opencv ; you need to think on frmes per second , and do little research on SD Card speed as well ,because slower SD card will slow performance as well

Comment: yeah , thanks to u
i had searched for very optimized SD card class 10 sandisk and really make big difference
But while working on , Due to heavy image processing , the processor was responding very tired on raspbian image